# Autowire specific implementations of persistence layer in Spring with Java based configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, persistence, spring-data

In a Spring MVC proyect I'm using Spring Data in the persistence layer so I have a bunch of repositories to access the data. I also have a layer for services so I have things like UserService or AuthorityService that use that repositories.

The problem is that I've been asked to create an interface to be able to change the implementation of the persistence layer (using DAOs for example) without have to touch a single line in the services. How can I specify in an Autowired of that interface what implementation to use? I´m using Java based config and I don't see how to inject it.

I also have a problem with the name of these new interfaces. Normally I would use a name like UserService but Spring use Service for the service layer so, What name is suitable for this type of interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could mark the new implementation of the DAO as [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html). Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency. If exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be the autowired value.

```
@Component
 public class FooService {
     private FooRepository fooRepository;

     @Autowired
     public FooService(FooRepository fooRepository) {
         this.fooRepository = fooRepository;
     }
 }

 @Component
 public class JdbcFooRepository {
     public JdbcFooService(DataSource dataSource) {
         // ...
     }
 }

 @Primary
 @Component
 public class HibernateFooRepository {
     public HibernateFooService(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
         // ...
     }
 }
```

Because `HibernateFooRepository` is marked with `@Primary`, it will be injected preferentially over the jdbc-based variant assuming both are present as beans within the same Spring application context, which is often the case when component-scanning is applied liberally.

This annotation is semantically equivalent to the  element's primary attribute in Spring XML.

I didn't completely follow your second question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I would like to be able to do this from a config file like I would do if I were using XML. About the second question, in most of the examples I've found, the service layer (bussiness) use names like UserService, AuthorityService, etc. My question is, how can I name the new interfaces. Use again Service would be too ambiguous.

Comment: Updated the post for the xml part. Are you saying spring data marks the service layer interface beans with *Service?